# Javascript merging objects within an array based on specific value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
var dictionary = this.props.posts
const postItemsArr = Object.keys(dictionary).map(post=>dictionary[post])
```

Which generates something like this:
[Image to show exactly what I get from postItemsArr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK33h.png)

This is format for 0(objects), 1(array) where in this case 0 would be busineses; where has 1 would be array of jobs.

```
"jobs":[  
      {  
         "jobId":"Ky4j9mV",
         "instabook":0,
         "be_name":"Faun Skyles",
         "min_comp":"asdasdasd",
         "businessID":"1770"
      },
      {  
         "jobId":"Ky4j9mV",
         "instabook":0,
         "be_name":"Faun Skyles",
         "min_comp":"asdasdasd",
         "businessID":"1771"
      }
   ]
  "businesses":{
    "1770":{
      "neighborhood":name
    }
     "1771":{
      "neighborhood":name
    }
  }
```

My Goal is to;
as you can see postItemsArr gives me multiple array in it;
I want to create a new array; and compare items inside postItemsArray.

So we have following: [0],[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK33h.png) as shown in picture.

```
[1] --> "1770":{
          "neighborhood":"green"
        }
         "1771":{
          "neighborhood":"black"
        }

[0] --> [  
          {  
             "jobId":"Ky4j9mV",
             "instabook":0,
             "be_name":"Faun Skyles",
             "min_comp":"asdasdasd",
             "businessID":"1770"
          },
          {  
             "jobId":"Ky4j9mV",
             "instabook":0,
             "be_name":"Faun Skyles",
             "min_comp":"asdasdasd",
             "businessID":"1771"
          }
       ]
```

So 0, and 1 they have something in common that is businessID; now I want to create a new array; and merge 1,2 into one dictionary.

output:`[business1objectwithId1770,business1objectwithId1771]`

So we're joining Jobs, businesses array within an array.

So in this case output would be like this:

```
"jobs":[  
      {  
         "jobId":"Ky4j9mV",
         "instabook":0,
         "be_name":"Faun Skyles",
         "min_comp":"asdasdasd",
         "businessID":"1770"
         "neighborhood":"green"

      },
      {  
         "jobId":"Ky4j9mV",
         "instabook":0,
         "be_name":"Faun Skyles",
         "min_comp":"asdasdasd",
         "businessID":"1771"
         "neighborhood":"black"

      }
   ]
```

note how I want neighborhood merge from businesses object to jobs array respective to their businessID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### If you want to return a new array based on the value of something use `filter`.

### Example 1

`const postItemsArr = Object.keys(dictionary).filter(post=>dictionary[post] === 'somevaluetofilter')`

This example will return all the values that are equal to `somevaluetofilter`.

### Example 2

`const filterJobsById = this.state.jobs.filter(item => item.businessID === 1771)`

This will return an array with the object that contains the business id 1771

### Merging A nested objects attribute with object in array that contains the equivalent id

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    jobs: [
      {
        jobId: "Ky4j9mV",
        instabook: 0,
        be_name: "Faun Skyles",
        min_comp: "asdasdasd",
        businessID: "1770"
      },
      {
        jobId: "Ky4j9mV",
        instabook: 0,
        be_name: "Faun Skyles",
        min_comp: "asdasdasd",
        businessID: "1771"
      }
    ],
    businesses: {
      "1770": {
        neighborhood: "SF"
      },
      "1771": {
        neighborhood: "los angeles"
      }
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { jobs, businesses } = this.state;
    const allIds = Object.keys(businesses).map(item => item);
    const updatedJobs = jobs.map((item, index) => {
      console.log(businesses[allIds[index]].neighborhood);
      return {
        jobId: item.jobId,
        instabook: item.instabook,
        be_name: item.be_name,
        min_comp: item.min_comp,
        businessID: item.businessID,
        location: allIds.includes(item.businessID)
          ? businesses[item.businessID].neighborhood
          : null
      };
    });

    console.log("updated", updatedJobs);
    console.log(allIds);
    return (
      <div>
        <p> {updatedJobs.map(item => <div> This is the location added {item.location} </div> </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

This will merge the arrays the way you want. Quite simply we check if the businessID is contained within the businesses nested object data structure. If it is then we know that we can use that ID to acess the location.

`allIds.includes(item.businessID)
          ? businesses[item.businessID].neighborhood
          : null`

If the ID exists grab the neighborhood, if it does not then we have no neighborhood for that business. Thus the location will be `null`.

`businesses[item.businessID].neighborhood` can be rewritten as the following.

- `businesses[1770].neighborhood` which is equal to "SF"
- `business[1771].neighborhood` which is equal to "LA"

We acess the object by its `key`, and the IDS are the `keys`.

[image: Edit merge attribute of nested objects with object within array containing an equivalent id]

Comment: How would this work on my example? if I were to compare businessID values?

Comment: could businesses be an array of objects or does it have to be an object of objects?

Comment: It can be array of objects

Comment: But I think you're missing my question.
I've refactored the main thread.

Comment: Right, so new array would contain new set of dictionaries this time with added key neighborhood for responding businessID

Comment: const postItemsArr = Object.keys(dictionary).map(post=>dictionary[post])
That alone has a LONG list of business IDs, I just don't want to merge specific business ID, I want to merge any business ID within that list. So I have 1 main array, within that 1 main array, I have objects/arrays, I'm trying to merge my objects and arrays based on arrays object key businessID and object key which is representation of businessID

Comment: I've added my dictionary variable too by the way.

Comment: please check my updated answer it should really help you

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to be a bit lazy and assume you've already got your filtered list and now you're just looking to merge. You can simply just `find` the element and append the data to it.

The changes go through because of how javascript handles objects (which is referencing).

```js
let toMerge = { "1770":{
          "neighborhood":"green"
        },
         "1771":{
          "neighborhood":"black"
        }
}

let filtered = [  
          {  
             "jobId":"Ky4j9mV",
             "instabook":0,
             "be_name":"Faun Skyles",
             "min_comp":"asdasdasd",
             "businessID":"1770"
          },
          {  
             "jobId":"Ky4j9mV",
             "instabook":0,
             "be_name":"Faun Skyles",
             "min_comp":"asdasdasd",
             "businessID":"1771"
          }
       ]
       
for (let key in toMerge)
{
  let theElement = filtered.find( element => element.businessID == key)

  for (let innerKey in toMerge[key])
  {
    theElement[innerKey] = toMerge[key][innerKey]
  }
  
}

console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: I tried like this:https://pastebin.com/VGZ6MYMH
It threw me error:
TypeError: Cannot set property 'address' of undefined @a-lau

remind you; when I did typeof() for both toMerge, filtered, I got objects

Comment: @zennn you're better off giving me a fiddle of what you did instead so i can actually run it.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/2cQ3d ---> to merge (I console logged dictionary.businesses)
https://imgur.com/a/BYHHe --->filtered data(I console logged dictionary.jobs
I cannot setup fiddle; it's a react component. @a-lau

Comment: You shouldn't have to. React is still JavaScript. The only time when it's an actual React problem is when you're trying to display it or you're having issue with the router or any actual react related functionalities. If you tried a `typeof` and it's an object, then you need to fix up your question first, probably changing it so the data matches what you have.